# FFTW3 2D, passing fftw_complex array

Tags: c, error-handling, syntax-error, fft, fftw

I am trying to implement the directions in [here](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Fixed_002dsize-Arrays-in-C.html#Fixed_002dsize-Arrays-in-C) to calculate 2D Fourier transform:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include </usr/local/include/fftw3.h>
#include <math.h>

#define NUM_POINTS 600

#define REAL 0
#define IMAG 1

void acquire_from_somewhere(fftw_complex *signal) {

    int i, j, m_gamma=2, Lambda=1;
    double theta=0.095,kappa=5.;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_POINTS; ++i) {
    for (j = 0; j < NUM_POINTS; ++j) {
    double x = (double)i / (double)NUM_POINTS * M_PI, y = (double)j / (double)NUM_POINTS * M_PI;

    signal[i][j][REAL] = Lambda*cos(theta/2)*cos(theta/2)*cos(m_gamma * atan(y/x));

    signal[i][j][IMAG] =0.;
    }}
}

void do_something_with(fftw_complex *result, double *mag) {
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_POINTS; ++i) {
    for (j = 0; j < NUM_POINTS; ++j) {
        *mag = sqrt(result[i][j][REAL] * result[i][j][REAL] + result[i][j][IMAG] * result[i][j][IMAG]);

        printf("%g\n", *mag);
    }}
}


/* Resume reading here */

int main() {

    double mag;
    fftw_complex signal[NUM_POINTS][NUM_POINTS];
    fftw_complex result[NUM_POINTS][NUM_POINTS];

    fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_2d(NUM_POINTS,NUM_POINTS,
                                  &signal[0][0],
                                  &result[0][0],
                                  FFTW_FORWARD,
                                  FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    acquire_from_somewhere(&signal[0][0]);
    fftw_execute(plan);
    do_something_with(&result[0][0], &mag);

//    printf("%g\n", mag);

        fftw_destroy_plan(plan);

        return 0;
}
```

I get the following kind of errors:

```
FFT.c:26:21: error: subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector
    signal[i][j][REAL] = Lambda*cos(theta/2)*cos(theta/2)*cos(m_gamma * atan(y/x));//Lambda*(cos(theta/2)*cos(theta/2)*cos(m_gamm...
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
```

I am not sure where to look... I suppose, conventional way of passing the 2D array doesn't work for fftw_complex. How to fix my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

```
fftw_complex *signal
```

Indicates a pointer to an `fftw_complex` is being passed, possibly a decayed 1D array.

A 3D array decays into a pointer to a 2D array. So you should have written that argument as

```
fftw_complex (*signal)[][]
```

Also in your question, you talk about 2D arrays yet treat `signal` as a 3D array, inconsistent.

Comment: Thank you! According to the manual fftw_complex [size][size] is 2D, with the third implicit dimension [1]-imaginary and [0]-real. If I said 3D, one might have thought about fftw_complex [size][size][size] case... I follow the manual definitions.

Comment: This way I get: error: array has incomplete element type 'fftw_complex []'
void acquire_from_somewhere(fftw_complex (*signal)[][])